# Eas build In react project Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I am having a lot of issues trying to make an Android build using EAS build. the bellow is the error i am getting, it is also worth noting that I am able to make IOS builds without much issues.

Before migration to EAS we had no issues building projects using expo build.

```
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
[stderr] 
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
[stderr] 
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
[stderr] 
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
[stderr] 
     Required by:
[stderr] 
         project :app
[stderr] 
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' but:
[stderr] 
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 1m 26s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```